# 'get' returning blank value python

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

i tried this code but i am getting blank response from get command??
it is only in the class i am getting blank value..but if i make a function rather than a class i am getting value from text ...

```
from Tkinter import *
from ttk import Button,Entry,Style
import pickle
class Home(Frame):
    def __init__(self,parent):
         Frame.__init__(self,parent)
         self.parent=parent
         self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.parent.title("HOME SCREEN")
        frame = Frame(self)
        global a
        global z


        self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)
        label1=Label(frame,text="USERNAME",)
        label2=Label(frame,text="PASSWORD")
        text1=Entry(frame, show="*", width=15)
        text2=Entry(frame,width=15)
        login=Button(self,text="Login",command=self.load)
        register=Button(self,text='Register',command=self.dump)
        Quit=Button(self,text='Quit',command=self.quit)
        delete=Button(self,text='Delete Account',command=self.delete)
        showb=Button(self,text='Show Accounts',command=self.show)

        label1.pack(side=LEFT)
        text2.pack(side=LEFT, padx=5, pady=5)
        label2.pack(side=LEFT )
        text1.pack(side=LEFT, padx=5, pady=5)
        frame.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)

        Quit.pack(side=RIGHT ,padx=5, pady=5)
        register.pack(side=RIGHT)
        login.pack(side=RIGHT)
        delete.pack(side=RIGHT)
        showb.pack(side=RIGHT)

        a=text1.get()
        z=text2.get()
```

Comment: Are you using TKinter? Imports would be nice...

Comment: yes i am using Tkinter

Comment: i am not a fool not to import it..... i am getting blank value from the entry by using get function

Answer (score -5, accepted):

Figured it out my self...

```
def initUI(self):
    self.parent.title("HOME SCREEN")


    frame = Frame(self)

    self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)
    label1=Label(frame,text="USERNAME",)
    label2=Label(frame,text="PASSWORD")
    text1=Entry(frame, show="*", width=15,)
    text2=Entry(frame,width=15)
    login=Button(self,text="Login",command=self.load)
    register=Button(self,text='Register',command=self.dump)
    Quit=Button(self,text='Quit',command=self.quit)
    delete=Button(self,text='Delete Account',command=self.delete)
    showb=Button(self,text='Show Accounts',command=self.show)


    label1.pack(side=LEFT)
    text2.pack(side=LEFT, padx=5, pady=5)
    label2.pack(side=LEFT )
    text1.pack(side=LEFT, padx=5, pady=5)
    frame.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)

    Quit.pack(side=RIGHT ,padx=5, pady=5)
    register.pack(side=RIGHT)
    login.pack(side=RIGHT)
    delete.pack(side=RIGHT)
    showb.pack(side=RIGHT)
    global text1
    global text2
def dump(self):

    z=(text1.get())
    a=(text2.get())
```

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `text1.get()` and `text2.get()` before the GUI appears on the screen, so there's no way the user can enter text before you try to get the value. You need to move these calls inside a function that is called after the user has a chance to enter information in the widget.